# no such mongoid configuration file issue

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a minitest_helper.rb and mongoid.yml files in a directory. I putted the below code in minitest_helper;

```
require 'mongoid'
Mongoid.load!("mongoid.yml", :test)
```

Although these files in a same directory, Mongoid couldn't load yml file and I got 'no such file' as below:

```
/home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/config
/environment.rb:40:in `initialize': No such file or directory - mongoid.yml
(Errno::ENOENT)
```

Also I don't use any framework like Rails, Sinatra etc.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Config#load!-instance_method), the `#load!` needs the full path to the file. Try changing the code into something like this:

```
Mongoid.load!(File.join('path_to_the_yml','starting_at_root_of_the_project', 'mongoid.yml') , :test)
```

The way you construct the `File.join` will depend on your directory structure. If I had an structure such as this:

```
project_root
--lib
--spec
----fixtures
------test.xml  # the path for this file is project_root/spec/fixtures/test.xml
```

Then the `File.join` will look like this:

```
File.join('spec','fixtures', 'test.xml')
```